# Add tracking code to existing pdf to track pdf open. The pdf is as attachment emailed to the customer, not located on the server

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to add tracking codes to existing pdf to track whether the customer opens it. When I use iTextSharp-PdfStamper.JavaScript, it can be tracked when the pdf is opened. But I don't want the url to be opened in a window. Is there any way to just call this tracking url, but won't open in a window?

Codes below:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);

PdfReader reader    = new PdfReader (@".\input.pdf");
FileStream output   = new FileStream(@".\output.pdf", FileMode.Create);

PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output, '\0', true);
pdfStamper.JavaScript = "app.launchURL('http://mysitedomain/trackingcodeurl',false);";

pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
pdfStamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

What you are asking is illegal without the direct consent of your customers.
Unless you can guarantee that nobody in the EU will ever open your document, in which case the law does not apply to them.

I'll cite some bullet points relevant for email-tracking, but you can easily derive the conclusions for document tracking.

- Under the GDPR, “personal data” is defined as any information that identifies an individual. That includes email addresses, what browser a person is using, and their actions.
- The collection of the email tracking information listed above without consent is strictly prohibited by GDPR.

Check out https://www.pipedrive.com/en/blog/gdpr-email-tracking